# How to disambiguate

Tags: swift

I have what looks like a simple namespace/scope question here. I remember the Swift designers discussing the use of some kind of annotation like `@....` that could solve this type issue. How do I disambiguate

```
class A {
}

class B {
  enum BEnum {}
}

extension A {
   enum B {
       static let x = B.BEnum // Type 'A.B' has no member 'BEnum'
   }
}
```

Comment: You can prefix it with the module name that defines it, e.g. `Swift.String` insteaad of just `String`.

Comment: can you make this your answer? I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alexander has highlighted, you can use the module name that defines `B`. Since `B` is likely to be defined in your project, you can use the project's name to access the top-level class:

```swift
class A {
}

class B {
  enum BEnum {}
}

extension A {
   enum B {
     static let x = ProjectName.B.BEnum.self
   }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are defining a package, replace `ProjectName` with your `ModuleName`.